# Verb+s/es vs Verb

Tags: grammar

> 1. **It works**✔*.It work❌*
> 2. **Nobody/No one works**✔*.Nobody/no one work.❌*
> 3. **Anybody/Anyone works**✔*.Anybody/anyone work❌*
> 4. **Everybody/Everyone works**✔*.Everybody/everyone work❌*
> 5. **That works**✔*.That work❌*
> 6. **This works**✔*.This work❌*
> 7. **Those work**✔*.Those works❌*
> 8. **These work**✔*.These works❌*
> 9. **What works**✔*.What work❌*
> 10. **Who works**✔(for singular)
> 11. **Who work**✔(for plural)
> 12. **Which works**✔(for singular)
> 13. **Which work**✔(for plural)

Am I right?

Comment: @Mari-LouA not a lot, but I can't see this Q surviving, and the previous title was ridiculous.

Comment: @Mari-LouA; my name is actually **over** the edit!

Comment: @Mari-LouA; well it's not now!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to identify the specific point of grammar / linguistics / etc that you'd like to have addressed. Is it a matter of numerical agreement with the word *work(s)*? If so, what have you found so far on that topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interrogative *who* can be used with a plural verb only under certain conditions. Otherwise, *who* functions as the subject of its clause and takes a singular verb even when the expected answer is plural:

> Who works for Company A? Those six people over there.

A who-interrogative can have a plural verb only with *are, were* when used alone as a linking verb, not in a progressive *are working*:

> Who are those six people over there? They're the ones who work for Company A.

This is because the interrogative pronoun can be parsed as a predicate nominative rather than the subject "people."

This is not the case in Indian English, where one often meets constructions such as:

> [Who all work for](https://broadbandforum.co/threads/who-all-work-for-mtnl.24606/page-2) [some company]?

In Indian English, *who all* is the plural of *who*, but this is not the case in other dialects of English.

A who-interrogative can be followed by a plural verb also when, in informal speech, it is inquiring about the object of a verb rather than its subject. In more formal registers, one would expect *whom*:

> Who do your parents know here?

---

Using *which* with a plural verb would require adding a plural noun, *ones*, or some partitive construction to cue the plural:

> Which cookies have butter?
>
> Which ones are broken?
>
> Which of the two alternatives do you prefer?

Comment: *Who all wants to go?* is a normal phrasing in the southern US.

Comment: Right. I might could've included that, but the _all_ only solicits a thorough and plural answer. The verb is still singular. _Who all_ in Indian English is a true plural.